# SAS: Transform variable into time series in text file import - length greater than 32.767

Tags: sas

I get a calendar file from a vendor containing all holidays for a specific calendar.

The file contain 7 columns separated by a pipe (|). However column 7 that contain the actual holiday comes in a string format separated by semi-colon (;).

My problem is that column 7 has a length greater than 32.767 - then the solution I have done so far using some array and transpose tricks doesn't work anymore.

Basically the text file looks like:

```
INTERNAL_NAME|ERROR_CODE|NUMBER_OF_FIELDS|CALENDAR_CODE|CALENDAR_TYPE|CALENDAR_NAME|DATES

US|0|4|US|Country|United States|;2;15728;1;5;19440101;5;19440102;5;19440103;5;19440108;5;19440109......etc.
```

However column 7 is delivered in a nice format so that the size of the array/matrix is given and the delimiter is given at the start of the string.

*1st charachter = delimiter  ->  ;

*Number of dimensions in matrix -> 2

*Number of rows in matrix -> 15.728

*Number of columns -> 1

*Data elements + Data -> 5 = Date and Data=01JAN1944 etc.

My desired result would be a dataset looking like

```
INTERNAL_NAME DATES
US      01JAN1944
US      02JAN1944
US      03JAN1944
US      08JAN1944
```

etc. until 15.728 observations is read.....

Comment: What about the other column in your array?

Comment: Hi Tom, the other column would of course also be needed. The suggested code from @Joe takes care of that. But thanks for noticing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily.

The manual solution, i.e., assuming the fields are just as you say they are, is to use the secondary delimiter (`;`) and then you can parse that initial string on your own later since it's known to be shorter.  Then iterate the inputs of that string, using `@` to hold the line.

```
data want;
infile datalines4 dlm=';' truncover;
length initial_string $500;
input initial_String $ @;
input dim row col @;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (missing(holiday_date));
  input col_type holiday_Date @;
  if not missing(holiday_date) then output;
end;
datalines4;
US|0|4|US|Country|United States|;2;15728;1;5;19440101;5;19440102;5;19440103;5;19440108;5;19440109
;;;;
run;
```

If you want to use that information that tells you about the delimiter/etc. to drive the readin, you could do that, but it would take two passes on the data file (unless it has a limited set of possibilities and you could just use if/else branching with those limited set of input statements).  One pass would read just that part, then call a macro to read in the rest in a separate data step.  But if this is always the format of the file, and you don't really care about those fields - you just have to work with them being there - the above is probably better as it's faster and less complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Good of just setting the delimiter to ; from the outset - dont know why I didnt think of that.

Comment: The sexy solution would of course be to use the information from about delimiter etc. so that the code would be as generic as possible. But in order to get moving I can totally live with the proposed solution for now. Unfortunately, see code doesnt handle the problem with lenght more than 32767. Hence, I only get 2.975 observation and not the full range of dates due to the field being so long. Any suggestions to solving that issue?

Comment: Maybe your LRECL is not set or is not set properly?  LRECL defaults I think to 32767.  But it can be 1M or more.

Comment: I actually manually set it to 32.767 as I thought it was maximum. I just tried with 1M and now it works :) Thank you so much for your help - how do I credit you?

Comment: There is a checkmark to indicate this answer was correct/the most helpful.  As far as 32767 being the maximum - it is if you want to use _INFILE_ variable, but assuming you're not doing that, it's whatever the maximum is on your operating system (at least 1M).